# Rotating a vector without the use of trigonometric functions

Tags: c++, math, 3d

Let's say in an environment I don't have easy access to trig functions, or I just don't want to use them for some reason. Is there any possible way to rotate a vector by a unit angle without cos/sin?

Comment: If your representation of a vector is (lenght,angle), yes. It's a simple addition then.

Comment: Mat, no, actually it's (x,y,z), sorry for the possible misunderstanding.

Comment: I have never implemented it myself, but the CORDIC algorithm (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORDIC) is what you're looking for.

Comment: @mtrw Yeap. +1. Have done this with VHDL. Vastly faster than software cosine calculations :)

Comment: mtrw, if you put that in an answer I would accept it.

Comment: You only need a table with 90 values.

Comment: Have you considered using quaternions instead of angles to represent and perform spatial rotation ([see wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could precompute the rotation matrix. But that doesn't sound like what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I'm 10 years too late, but if anyone else has a similar problem, let me share my little trick that
works for small radius with up to 16 angles. You can't use it for sophisticated rotation,
but it'll work for games such as Pong, Breakout, Asteroids, etc. It is int only and no trigonometry.

The trick is very simple. All you need to do is divide circle to 4 quadrants, and then understand
that (signs are specific for each quadrant)

Assume that I am in the right, top quadrant. if I move
...1 pixel right it is 0 degree angle.
...1 pixe up it is a 90 degree angle
...1 pixel right and 1 pixel up it is 45 degree
...2 pixels right and 1 pixel left it is 22.5 deg
...1 pixel right and 2 pixels up it is 67.5 deg

And there you have it. By changing signs for each quadrant you can generate simple paths
at each of these angles. And these paths repeat themselves after 2 pixels so if you are calculating
next position from current position and it is a linear movement (such as a ball at pong),
then you can easily calculate next position using just this logic.

Answer (score 0):

The only easy way for doing so is implementing your own trigonometric functions. Why can't you use trigonometric functions?